# React Native for Android TV. Disable inbuilt spatial navigation

Tags: android, react-native, navigation, focus, spatial

I am developing an Android TV application using React Native, but the inbuilt spatial navigation (and focus system) is unpredictable and entirely unusable for my purpose.
I want to control on my own the spatial navigation using the keydown events, but, once I add a FlatList in my code, the flat list takes the focus and my keydown event code is ignored.

Is there a way to fully disable the inbuilt focus system in react native?

On flutter it is easily doable, but it doesn't support Apple TVOS